# Bash: How can I grep a line for multiple instances of the same string?

Tags: regex, bash, grep

I've got several lines that look like this:

```
aaaaaaaaxzaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
bbbbbbbbbbbbxzbbbbbbxzbb
ccxzcccccccccccccccccxzc
dddddddxzddddddddddddddd
```

Inside two of those lines, there are **two** instances of `xz` characters. I want grep to look for `xz` twice in the same line and output the lines that it matches on. If `xz` appears once, I don't want to know.

Running the following:

```
cat lines | grep "xz"
```

Tells me every line with xz on, but I only want to see lines with xz appearing twice.

How can I make the pattern search repeat in the same line?

Comment: `cat lines | grep -oP 'xz.*xz'`?

Comment: that works stribizhev, thank you

Comment: No need for `-P` or `-o`.

Comment: -oP is needed if you don't know how much times the pattern occurs inside the line. For N=2 you can use 'xz.*xz', but it is not general solution. In case of arbitrary N `cat lines | grep -oP xz` is the proper solution.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use

```
cat lines | grep 'xz.*xz'
```

Or  just

```
grep 'xz.*xz' lines
```

The `.*` will match optional characters (any but a newline) between 2 `xz`.

In case you need to use look-arounds, you will need `-P` switch to enable Perl-like regexps.

Comment: this won't print the whole line, instead, it prints many matched patterns, due to the `-o`

Comment: one more problem, OP mentioned **two** instances. if one line has three (or more) `xz`, your grep will print it out too. pls fix

Comment: It is not a big issue. The regex to get a line with just two `xz` is [`^(?:(?:(?!xz).)*xz){2}(?:(?!xz).)*$`](https://regex101.com/r/mK7hS1/1). From OP's feedback it seems there must be **at least 2** `xz`.

Comment: Just in case one wants to use `grep` with the above pattern, use `grep -P '^(?:(?:(?!xz).)*xz){2}(?:(?!xz).)*$' file`.

Answer (score 7):

awk is one way to go:

```
awk -F'xz' 'NF==3' file
```

or

```
awk 'gsub(/xz/,"")==2' file
```

another benefit awk brings you is, it is easier to check a pattern matched `less then n times`, `exact n times` or `greater than n times`. you just change the `==` into `<, <=, >, >=`

Answer (score 1):

If you want to output the matching lines in full you don't need the options

```
grep 'xz.*xz' filename
```

will do

Comment: What if you want two of the same string? Try the pattern `[x-z]\{2\}` and you'll see that "xy abc yx" matches just as well as "xy abc xy". In general I think the solution should only involve specifying the pattern to match once. I can get this done, but so far not with a simple pattern match.

Comment: what you described can be done with back reference `grep -E '(..).*\1'` will match where any two chars are repeated, but that's not what been asked here,,,

Comment: I guess I assumed that when I read 'xz' and didn't see any other 'x' or 'z'. You are right though.